# Fabric - "fit" mode for images instead of stretching on resize

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric to display an image in a canvas. By default, the resize action stretches the image by breaking its aspect ratio. Is there an option I can use to avoid stretching the image but allow the control box to be resized?

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('demo', {
  backgroundColor: '#DDDEEE',
  centeredScaling: true,
  centeredRotation: true
});
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 540;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.setDimensions({ width: CANVAS_WIDTH, height: CANVAS_HEIGHT });


fabric.Image.fromURL('https://via.placeholder.com/300', (img) => {
  canvas.add(img);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.2.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
<canvas id="demo"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

[resize and fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmlB.png)